# See Mercurial changeset summary/user/date

Tags: mercurial

Given a Mercurial changeset 123, how can yous see the summary, user, and date associated with the changeset?  Figured there was an `hg log` option but couldn't see it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `hg log -r 123`?

Answer (score 8):

you can also try [Mercurial Templates](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html) to get just the output you're after. Several keywords are supported, but in your example this command would work:

```
hg log -r 123 --template '{author}\n{date}\n{desc}\n'
```